# Devolver valor al main en C

Tags: c

¿Como puedo conseguir que desde `int datos_semana` se devuelva el valor `suma` al `int main` y alli ya se imprima el valor de

```
int main( ){
  float suma;
  datos_semana( );

  printf( "%f", suma );
}

int datos_semana( ) {
  int num = 0, max = 0, min = 0, contador = 0, suma = 0;
  printf( "Introduce 7 numeros para ver max. min. y mediaºn" );
  scanf( "%d", &num );

  max = num;
  min = num;
  suma = num;

  while( contador < 6 ) {
    printf( "Inserte otro número: \n" );
    scanf( "%d", &num );

    if( num > max ) {
      max = num;
    } else if( num < min ) {
      min = num;
    }

    suma += num; //suma=suma+num;   
    contador++;
  }

  return( suma );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de hacerlo es como lo tienes, pero asignando tu variable `suma` a tu función `datos_semana();`

```
suma = datos_semana();
```

De esta manera, al retornar los datos en la función suma, tendrá el valor de la suma total de los numero introducidos.

Tu código completo quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int datos_semana(void);
float suma;

int main()
{
    suma = datos_semana();
    printf("\nSuma total: %.2f",suma); //%.2f --> sirve para visualizar 2 decimales
}

int datos_semana(void)
{
    int num=0,max=0,min=0,contador=0,suma=0;
    printf ("Introduce 7 n%cmeros para ver max. min. y media: ",163);// %c y el numero 163 sirve para mostrar correctamente la u con tilde
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    max=num;
    min=num;
    suma=num;

    while (contador<6){
        printf("Inserte otro n%cmero: ",163); // 
        scanf ("%d",&num);
        if (num>max){
            max=num;
        }else if (num<min){
            min=num;
        }
        suma+=num;//suma=suma+num;  
        contador++;
    }

    return(suma);
}
```

Si te fijas en los comentarios que he puesto en el código, te darás cuenta que he añadido una forma para poner la u de número con tilde. Esto se consigue poniendo `%c` en el lugar del carácter en cuestión y luego al final un valor *ASCII* que corresponde con el carácter acentuado.  [Tabla ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/codigos-ascii/letra-a-minuscula-codigo-ascii-97.html)

Espero que sea de utilidad!

Comment: Me ha funcionado poniendo en vez de float suma = datos_semana(), suma = datos_semana(), es decir, quitando el float. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Te funciona quitando el tipo de variable? Tendrás declarada la variable en otra parte de tu código no?

Comment: @Edurex Si la respuesta ha solucionado tu problema o ha contribuido en gran medida a ello, lo correcto es marcarla como *aceptada*, pulsando el símbolo del *check* ( `✔` ) a la izquierda de la respuesta. ¿ Quizás deberías pasarte por [La Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber como funciona el sitio ? Un saludo.